# What are the best practices for working with keyboard and mouse events in Flambe?

Tags: haxe, flambe

I have read the [relevant post in the Flambe guide](https://github.com/markknol/flambe-guide/wiki/Touch-mouse-keyboard) but couldn't see any use of the clone() function. The APIs of the various event classes (like the [PointerEvent class](https://aduros.com/flambe/api/flambe/input/PointerEvent.html)) contain this note:

> NOTE: For performance reasons, PointerEvent instances are reused by
>   Flambe. Use clone() to retain a reference to an event.

I have 3 questions:

1. Is it possible that a PointerEvent object will change even though my code is still working on it?
2. When should I use the clone() function?
3. Are there any other best practices that I should know about when dealing with events in Flambe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It *should* be the same in the same frame, but I'm not sure if this is certain. I use the rule, if you pass it to a different instance or want to reuse it later, clone it.
2. When you want to store the event in next frame. I personally mostly copy the viewX/viewY values into a custom point (for example in case you want to detect a swipe yourself) so then there is no need for the full event to be cloned, but that my preference.
3. [Always dispose the events](https://github.com/markknol/flambe-guide/wiki/Signal-Event-System#boom-dispose-signals). They return a `SignalConnection`. Make this a private member and dispose it in the `dispose` function, or register it to a `Disposer` if you use it. This avoids memory leaks and unwanted behavior.